# Applying rotation moves objects

Tags: transforms

I have a set of eyeballs made up of 2 meshes joined together, a pupil and an iris. When I apply rotation and scale, it moves them in different directions. How can I apply rotation, scale etc. without changing an object's transformations?
.blend file is below
[image]

Comment: could you please share this part of your file so that we can test? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sounds like your object is both eyes. Consider using an object per eye.

Comment: Ive got them as 2 seperate eyeballs....ive also tried separating the meshes but it doesn't work either. I've uploaded the .blend file to the post

Comment: Even though they are two separate objects, would do this.  Make one eye. Move it such that its origin is also at global  (0, 0, 0) when its location is (0, 0, 0)  (like the default cube)  Position the eyes using parenting.

Comment: Also note  the matrix parent inverse is set to rotate 360 around local x axis.   To re-iterate. Make the eye at global (0, 0, 0) origin there too.  Point the eye down an axis of choice.  Then position eye with a parent. Otherwise as you have found out applying transforms can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: ok so essentially use a parent to move the object as opposed to moving the object itself?Could you explain the matrix parent inverse  please forgive my ignorance, im pretty new to all this and that hasn't really come up before?